# Upper bound for $\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert$ given conditions (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Denote $\lVert \cdot\rVert=\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty$. Suppose $f: (\mathbb{R}^d,\lVert \cdot\rVert)\to(\mathbb{R},\lvert \cdot\rvert)$ bounded and absolutely integrable. Assume that $\exists\Delta,L<\infty$ such that:

(a)  $f(u)=0$ for $\lVert u\rVert>L$ (*compact support*) and $\forall u,u'\in \mathbb{R}^d$, we have $\lvert f(u)-f(u')\rvert\leq \Delta \lVert u-u'\rVert$ (*Lipschitz*)

or

(b) $f$ is differentiable with $\lvert f'(u)\rvert\leq\Delta$ (bounded gradient), and for some $v>1$, $\lvert f'(u)\rvert\leq\Delta\lVert u\rVert^{-v}$ for $\lVert u\rVert>L$ (gradient tends to zero with $u\to\infty$).

Then for any $\lVert x_1-x_2\rVert\leq \delta\leq L$,
$$\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert\leq \delta \Delta I(\lVert x_1\rVert\leq 2L)\text{, if (a) holds};$$
and
$$\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert\leq \delta \Delta [I(\lVert x_1\rVert\leq 2L)+ \lVert x_1-L\rVert^{-\eta} I(\lVert x_1\rVert> 2L)]\text{, if (b) holds}.$$

**My attempt**

If (a) holds, $\forall \delta>0:\delta\leq L:\lVert x_1-x_2\rVert\leq \delta$ implies
\begin{align}
\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert&\leq \Delta \lVert x_1-x_2\rVert \\
&\leq \delta \Delta  I(\lVert x_1\rVert\leq 2L)
\end{align}
since if the point $x_1$ is outside the closed ball with center $0$ and radius $2L$,$B_{2L}(0)$, it means the other point is outside $B_L(0)$, and then $f=0$.

How to obtain the result for (b)? I'm thinking if it's the case to use Mean Value Theorem.

**Update**

To justify the term
$\lVert x_1-L\rVert^{-\eta} I(\lVert x_1\rVert> 2L)$ under (b), from the Mean Value Theorem, for some $z=(1-c)x_1+cx_2, c\in(0,1)$
$$\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert\leq \lvert\nabla f(z)\rvert \lVert x_1-x_2\rVert$$
If $\lVert x_1\rVert> 2L$,
$$\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert\leq \Delta \lVert z\rVert^{-v} \delta$$
I'm struggling to show $\lVert x_1-L \rVert \leq \lVert z \rVert$ to get the result. For $d=1$, it is clear. But not so clear for higher dimensions

Comment: May I ask what does it mean the notation $I(\|x_{1}\|\leq 2L)$?

Comment: This is the indicator function. It's $1$ if the inequality holds and $0$ otherwise

Comment: Are you sure that it appears $\|x_{1} - L\|$ on your second problem? I'm asking because $x_{1} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $L > 0$ is a constant, so how is it defined $x_{1} - L$?

Comment: By the way, it looks right your answer for the first problem. The real problem is to show that $\|x_{1}\| > 2L$ implies that $\|x_{2}\| > L$. Which is true, since $2L - \|x_{2}\| <   \|x_{1}\| - \|x_{2}\| \leq \|x_{1} - x_{2}\| \leq L$ then, $L < \|x_{2}\|$. Then $|f(x_{1}) - f(x_{2})| = 0$.

Comment: @ABP https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/et_08.pdf see the page 741. This $L$ was given as a scalar. When he added $x_1-L$ I was considering $x_1 - L(1,...,1)$. But now, I really don't know. I was trying to see the problem geometrically. For the 1-dimensional case, the result is clear for me. But when $d>2$, this inequality (the one I'm trying to show) seems to fail.

Comment: As @ABP has noted, the term $x_{1}-L$ is not even meaningful.

Comment: I'm left to conclude that $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Unless the author made mistakes.

Comment: It wouldn't be so weird if by an abuse the authors has considered $L = (L, ..., L)$. Since as you're considering the norm $\|(u_{1}, ..., u_{n}) \| = \max\{|u_{i}|, i = 1,...,n\}$ you would have $\|u - L\| = \max\{|u_{i}|, i = 1,...,n\} - L = \|u\| - L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace $\|x_{1} - L\|$ by $\|x_{1}\| - L$ I guess it would work. Observe that, following your argument when you updated your question, we have to prove that: Given $z = (1-c)x_{1} + cx_{2}$ with $c \in (0, 1)$ then $\|x_{1}\| - L \leq \|z\|$. Note that: 
$$ \|x_{1} - z\| = c\|x_{1} - x_{2}\| \leq L$$
so,
$$ - L \leq - \|x_{1} - z\|$$
then,
$$\|x_{1}\| - L \leq \|x_{1}\| - \|x_{1} - z\| \leq \|x_{1} - (x_{1} - z)\| = \|z\| $$
but, the way that this inequality is stated is quite confusing. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!