# How to show the function is absolutely integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, self-learning

Let $f(u)=C(I(\lVert u\rVert\leq 2L)+\lVert u-L\rVert^{-v}I(\lVert u\rVert>2L))$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}, I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function, $\lVert x\rVert=\max(\lvert x_1\rvert,\dotsc,\rvert x_d\lvert)$, and $C,L,v<\infty$ positive constants.

Show that $\int_{R^d}\lvert f(u)\rvert du\leq M<\infty$.

I founded that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}I(\lVert u\rVert\leq 2L)du\leq (4L)^d$. The problem is to bound the second term, which seems integrable since , intuitively, as the coordinates go to infinity, the distance to $L$ increases, and then the term $\lVert u-L\rVert^{-v}$ decreases.
I'm unable to make this argument explicit. Can you help me?

*In addition,$\lVert u\rVert>2L$ implies that $u$ is outside the square centered at zero with sides $4L$. Then $\lVert u-L\rVert$ is strictly greater than $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $v>d$, then for $|u|>2L$, $|u-L|\geq|u|-L$, so the second term can be controlled by $\displaystyle\int_{|u|>2L}1/(|u|-L)^{v}$. Now we apply spherical, the integral is then $\omega_{n-1}\displaystyle\int_{2L}^{\infty}r^{d-1}/(r-L)^{v}dr\leq\omega_{n-1}2^{d-1}\int_{L}^{\infty}r^{d-1}/r^{v}<\infty$ since $v>d$.

Comment: I have some questions. As I'm working on Real numbers, does it matter what metric I choose to show this integrability? Seconfly, what is "apply spherical" ?

Comment: The metric is equivalent to the ball one, that is, the square root of square sums, in geometry, it is ball. Spherical integration is something you need to switch the integral so that you can compute in one-dimensional. Go Wiki check it out.

Comment: But did you see that I'm using the max norm? Geometrically, it's not a "ball" on $\mathbb{R}$. Rather, it's a square. But I remember that on real numbers, all metrics are equivalent...Maybe it does matter what metric I'm using, since it affects the region of integration. I'll see this spherical integration.

Comment: Still equivalent. The region just varies slightly. The point is this: Integration (in ball metric) $\int_{|x|>\delta}1/|x|^{v}dx$ is finite as long as $v>d$.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I asked a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406459/upper-bound-for-lvert-fx-1-fx-2-rvert-given-conditions-real-analysis    some hours ago. Can you try the last part (after my UPDATE)? That is, why $\lVert x_1-L \rVert \leq \lVert z \rVert$.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this integration technique that you used.  I read about cases where one seeks the volume of a $n$-ball. But we are integrating this symmetric function outside the closed $n$-ball of radius $2L$. Can you give me details of the steps used in your integration procedure?

Comment: By the way have you learnt the spherical integration?